# URL Aliasing using .htaccess

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting, masking

I have a directory 'Domainname1/folder/'. In Domainname1, I have a sub-directory which is a sub-domain (abc.mydomain.com) of another domain. This is a reference to 'domainname1/folder/'. The thing is I want the URL links accessing 'domainname1/folder/' to display the sub-domain definition. So instead of seeing:

```
'domainname1/folder/'
```

They see:

```
'abc.mydomain.com/path'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to redirect users ? or the user should be able to access both resources ?

Comment: user should be able to access the resources but the URL address should show with abc.mydomain/path

Answer (score 0):

you should use a reverse proxy to do such setup, here a [basic howto](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/reverse-proxy-apache.html).

Hope this would help you

Comment: This tutorial comes from a better source: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: actually i need a rewrite rule for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proxying abilities of mod_rewrite to achieve this. In the VirtualHost section for abc.mydomain, you can add:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain/folder/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain/folder
```

Comment: I probably didn't get you, with this explanation you confused me even further. Why don't you edit the question with a list URL FROM (request) => URL TO (response) examples? It would also be helpful to show what happens with this rule instead of what you want to happen.