# Masking Domain URL with Sub domain URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Hai i'm having a subdomain (abc.example.in) but this is referred to mydomain/folder . the thing is i want the mask URL links and the masked url should be displayed following with sub domain can any one help me out .

mydomain/folder/path

to

abc.example.in/path

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685763

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Aliasing using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685763/url-aliasing-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just rewrite all urls on mydomain/folder/path to abc.example.in/path and make sure all of the links in your app refer to the subdomain links?

The rewrite would be something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} http://[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*mydomain/folder/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)$ http://abc.example.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should match all requests to *.mydomain/folder/ and force them via a SEO-friendly 301 redirect to abc.example.in.